# Creating two classes: Main class and a Processing class

Tags: java, android, google-api

Suppose I have *two classes*, one is the *main* **class A** and the other is the class that helps in *processing results for A*, **class B**.

Suppose in *class A* I take *user input* **a1**, and **a2**. Then I have to send these inputs to class B for processing, and with these inputs, B *generates a result* **b1** and **b2**    *(which are not related to a1 and a2 independently, but a1 and a2 together generate these two results)*. And since class A being the main class, has to access b1 and b2 to display the results.

**How do I make this happen ??**

I currently am working on an **Android Program** that uses the `Distance-Matrix API`, and currently in my `MainActivity.java` class take user input, as well as do all the processing there itself. I really do want to move the processing part to another class but I am having problems with it. Sorry my Java basics is not that great. Can somebody please help ?

Comment: Read a tutorial about java classes and objects/instances. A good place to start is the [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/)

Comment: So have you tried anything yet?

Comment: well i did try ... but since my basics were nil, I couldn't actually access the results on the main class ...

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thank you ... i will definitely have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `A` and `B` are normal Java classes, then I suggest you make a simple `MyResults` class.

**Example**:

```
class MyResults {
final String b1;
final String b2;
public MyResults(final String b1, final String b2) {
    this.b1 = b1;
    this.b2 = b2;
}
public String getB1() { return b1; }
public String getB2() { return b2; }
```

The response of class `B` should be to return a `MyResults` class.

---

Now, if classes `A` and `B` happen to be Android `Activity` classes (i.e. "`class A extends Activity`") then throw all this out the window and pass results through the `Extras bundle` to be received in `A.onActivityResult()`. Super easy and standard to do, but you'll have to look for an example.